# How to replace special characters in a string using sed command in bash

Tags: bash, sed, quotes

I am passing a value to a .sh file as an argument (the file contains follows).

```
ESCAPED_REPLACE=$(printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed -e 's+$+\\$+g; s+(+\\(+g; s+"+\\"+g')
echo $ESCAPED_REPLACE
```

I basically want to replace every `$` with `\$` and every `(` with `\(`.

If I pass `Ver$ify`

```
./code.sh "Ver$ify"
```

I am getting `Ver\$` printed which should be `Ver\$ify` does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Research the difference between single and double quotes, see https://shellcheck.net, re-read a good introduction to shell scripting.

You do not pass `Ver$ify`, you are passing `Ver` with the result of `ify` variable. Use single quotes.

```
./code.sh 'Ver$ify'
```

> I basically want to replace every $ with `\$` and every ( with `\(`

```
sed 's/[$(]/\\&/g'
```